# Using an xml string within a BaseAdapter

Tags: android, xml, string, baseadapter

Is there any way to retrieve a string from my xml from an activity that extends BaseAdapter?

I do it this way:

```
public class testing extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Alarm alarm;
    String stringTest=context.getResources().getString(R.string.TXactive);
    private List<AlarmPreference> preferences = new ArrayList<AlarmPreference>();
    private final String[] repeatDays = {stringTest,"Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"};  
...
```

but the application crash.
I have searched for information about unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please pass context in constructor of baseadapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    MyAdapter adapter;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Model_CategoryMaster> itemArrayList;


    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model_CategoryMaster> itemsArray2) {
        context = c; //Update here

        itemArrayList = itemsArray2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        return itemArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return itemArrayList.get(position);
        // return itemArrayList.get(position % itemArrayList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.xml_row_category, null);
          String stringTest=context.getResources().getString(R.string.TXactive);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
stringTest=context.getResources().getString(R.string.TXactive);
```

to you constructor and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting crash because of your context. You need to pass the context from the activity to access the string resource.

Create constructor in your adapter as below and pass the context from your activity so that it will be able to get the resource.

```
public class testing extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
Public testing(Context p_context)
{
context=p_context;
}
```

In your activity do as below:

```
testing t1=new testing(MainActivity.this);
```